# Has anyone had any luck locating an old Tandy 1000 specific magazine called PCM by Falsoft publishing?

Tags: magazine, tandy-1000

I hope this is appropriate to ask here, if it's not, please let me know and I'll get it deleted.

So, for ***YEARS***, I have been searching high and low for old copies of a Tandy 1000 and Tandy portable specific magazine called **PCM**. It was published by Falsoft and has been out of print for a long time.

I used to read these magazines when I was a teenager and learned quite a bit from them. Now in my old age I'm looking to dive into that nostalgia puddle.

I've checked on archive.org, and they have a few issues uploaded, but naturally, I'm greedy and I want it all (and preferably legally) :)

So, does anyone have any info to help me in my (apparently never ending) search?

---

*Just so we're clear, I'm not talking about pirating this stuff, I'll buy it if I can find a reputable source.*

Comment: A few issues for sale on eBay.ca at least,. https://www.ebay.ca/sch/i.html?_nkw=PCM+Magazine

Comment: Thanks! I'm a little surprised at the price for a single magazine. They're asking for ~5x the original price (in CAD). I guess they figure the retro craze will allow for inflated pricing. Regardless, thank you again for locating that. I tried looking on Ebay last week and couldn't find a thing (probably bad search terms on my part).

Comment: Issue 2 is on archive.org - https://archive.org/search.php?query=creator%3A%22Professional+Computer+Magazine%22